# Send Power Bi Report outside of organization

Tags: powerbi

I don't underatand how to share a power bi report with an external email address. I am the only person in my power bi 'organisation' and have completed a report to share with a potential employer however I am unable to grant that person access to the report. Please could someone advise the easiest way to share a report with another email address that is not associated with my power bi account or advise how to grant that person access to the report or alternativley add that person to my power bi organsition or contacts?